# Best way to do bulk geocode look-up with Google Maps API

Tags: c#, .net, geocoding

Our company frequently receives large lists of addresses, upwards of 6000 that we need to geocode and put into our database. We already have a Google Maps API for Business License to get this done with.

I'm working on creating an application to do a bulk geocode look-up after I parse and separate the relevant parts of the list to make the URL to send off to Google. The parser is already done for me. I've tried making a separate thread for each address and sending a request to Google in the individual thread, and this works for a small number addresses (about 10 to 100), but  not for larger numbers (above 500). I get lots of 403 errors. So this probably isn't a good way to go about this. I also don't know too much about network programming, so I'm trying to learn as I go here.

So I'm wondering what the best way to do this might be. I can use VB.NET or C# to get this done; it doesn't matter too much. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be bumping up against Google's usage limits. Another option that's available to you is to use a commercial service that doesn't impose such limits.  One such service is the [US Street Address API](https://www.smarty.com/products/us-address-verification) from Smarty. This API allows you to send batches of addresses (up to 100 at a time) for verification and geocoding.  This API is geodistributed and will service requests as fast as it receives them.  There's a good amount of [sample code on github](https://github.com/smartystreets/smartystreets-dotnet-sdk) and you can sign up for a [free trial](https://www.smarty.com/pricing).

**Update**: SmartyStreets now provides [international address verification](https://www.smarty.com/products/international-address-verification).

Full disclosure: I'm a software developer at Smarty.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the option of switching. It's not up to me. And we've already paid for the license from Google. I will look into hitting the limit. I didn't think I'd actually gotten to 100,000 look-ups yet. My test case has about 6000 addresses in it and I've only run through it twice today.

Comment: Maybe slow down your request rate or divide requests over multiple IP addresses?

Comment: I think you're right about slowing down the request rate. Google will only take up to 10 requests per second and I was just sending out requests willy nilly. I fail at reading.